# Can't get xmlhttp.responseText value

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the xmlhttp.responseText value, but I have no response from the xmlhttp. I was wondering if there is something wrong with my code:

SCRIPT

```
var xmlhttp;

function show(){
    loadXMLDoc("includes/edit.php",function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
});
}


function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML

```
< a href="#" style="text-align: right; font-size: 10px;" onclick="show()">SHOW</a>
```

EDIT.PHP

```
print "1";
```

Comment: What about the console? Its everything ok there? Hit F12(in chrome), check and tell us what is says

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code per se, but there are a lot of interactions that are opaque from this code snippet.

I can offer some troubleshooting tips, however:

1. Add a console log in your callback function (the one that you are running alert() in). Just "console.log('function is running');" on the first line. Then see if you get that far. I would put one in the opening line of show() as well -- maybe your click event isn't doing what you think it is.
2. Have your PHP server-side file write something to a log so you can be sure that the request is being received where you think it is.
3. Open your browser developer console and watch the network panel. You should be able to see the entire XHR transaction there. Is it being sent at all? If so, is it returning the content you expect?
4. If all this doesn't help, setup a test in jsfiddle and post the link here. We'll be able to help in a lot more detail that way.

Good luck.

Comment: Troubleshooting advice belongs in comments. Answers should show what's actually wrong with the original code and how to fix it.